# Installing Laravel on Mac

Tags: php, macos, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have been trying to install Laravel (Latest version) on my Mac machine. I have all prerequisites such as php, composer. Just tried to execute below commands but it is giving errors.

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

Where,

-- /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php - Mac php path
-- composer.phar - Composer file

After executing the above command, I am getting error like below. I am using my office network, could that cause a firewall issue?

Error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

About my Mac:

OS X EI Captain (Version 10.11.6)

Comment: According to https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5685, you should try to use `http` to fetch those target first.

Comment: Thanks! but http not working for me :(

Comment: I really don't get it why do you have XAMPP on a MAC

Comment: Thank you! but tried to execute '/usr/bin/php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist' command. No luck on this too. I am getting the same error.

Comment: What error message did you get from http?

Answer (score 0):

In this case my suggestion is using Laravel Valet - never had issues with it. It will save you tones of time after you will start using it.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet
Also try to use global composer and clean composer's cache before doing that.
I think it was temporary issue.